Repeatedly getting very large diffs on github pull requests
I'm working on a project using GitHub to manage our workflow. We've got main and we cut a new release/24XX.XX branch for each release. When the release goes out the door we squash merge it back to main and cut a new release/XXXX.XX branch.
Development is done on feature branches and these are squashed into the current open release branch when they're ready. If someone has a release branch open when the new release branch is cut they merge that into their branch, and PR it into that new release branch.
Something's gone awry in the repository, sometimes when we raise a PR it shows 500+ changed files. If your branch needs updating from the new release, you might face 30+ conflicts when your PR only changed say 3 files. Resolving these conflicts and pushing the merge will result in the correct diff on the PR but this is obviously sub-optimal and has a large opportunity for error. This has been going on for the last two releases, we thought it would resolve once the previous release had been merged back to main but it hasn't.
How can we diagnose the issue?

Test if the problem goes away when using true merges. You don’t have to merge into your main. You could create test branches and do it in them.

I would bet the problem is that you are squashing.... If you are stacking up more stuff into the branch that you squash/merged into master and you are asking to merge that branch again into master later, then that is the problem.

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77630880/2437508

I am assuming that you are using Gitflows(i.e develop is development branch and main is release) Do you have protection rule on in main branch? If No then there is possibility that someone done rebase in main and force pushed, which changed commits' hash but content is same. To debug that, after release your develop and main should be same. Create PR from develop to main and main to develop It should have zero diff with zero changes. If it is not there then problem is your main and develop are diverged due to rebase and force push. Solution: You need to merge your main into develop.
